# sklearn StandardScaler outputting wrong matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

```
[10 15  18  11]
[15 17  24  16]
[13 13  20  14]
[12 20  10  25]
[12 11  14  11]
```

I have this data, and I'm trying to scale it using sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

scaled=scaler.fit_transform(df)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled, columns = df.columns)
scaled_df.head()
```

This outputs:

```
array([[-1.32680694, -0.06401844,  0.16552118, -0.85248268],
       [ 1.73505523,  0.57616596,  1.40693001,  0.11624764],
       [ 0.20412415, -0.70420284,  0.57932412, -0.27124449],
       [-0.30618622,  1.53644256, -1.4896906 ,  1.85996222],
       [-0.30618622, -1.34438724, -0.66208471, -0.85248268]])
```

I know this is wrong since the cov matrix shows variance as 1.25, when by definition it should be 1. Also, the original data is correctly saved in the 'df' variable. If I standarize the data manually I get the correct result, so I really don't know what's going on with the scaler function.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using the [pandas method std](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html), where the degree of freedom is by default 1. `StandardScaler` calls [numpy.std](https://enter%20link%20description%20here) which uses a degree of freedom of 0. If you set `ddof = 0` it should work.

To illustrate:

```
data = [[10 ,15 , 18 , 11],[15, 17,  24 , 16],[13, 13 , 20 , 14],
[12,20,10 ,25],[12, 11 , 14 , 11]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled=scaler.fit_transform(df)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled, columns = df.columns)

scaled_df

          0         1         2         3
0 -1.477098 -0.064018  0.165521 -0.852483
1  1.600189  0.576166  1.406930  0.116248
2  0.369274 -0.704203  0.579324 -0.271244
3 -0.246183  1.536443 -1.489691  1.859962
4 -0.246183 -1.344387 -0.662085 -0.852483

scaled_df.std()

0    1.118034
1    1.118034
2    1.118034
3    1.118034

scaled_df.std(ddof=0)

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
```